# Show that $\arctan\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)= x$

Tags: calculus

I'm a student of calculus and I am trying to get a grip of questions on old exams. The Questions i my exam will not be the same but the intuition will. This is a question about limits, where I'll have to show that my solution is correct.

The original question I'm now concerned with is
 $\arctan\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)= x$. I've always assumed this as a definition and, was perplexed when confronted with this. Don't even where to start.

When I did this I substituted,

$\arctan\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)= x$

$y= \tan\left(x\right)$

$\arctan\left(y\right)= \arctan\left(y\right)$

but seems like a closed circle and therefor wrong/not interesting.

Comment: This is by $arctan$ definition as the inverse of a restriction of $tan$ function to $(\frac {-\pi} 2,\frac {\pi} 2)$

Comment: It's not  always the case that $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$, not without some restrictions on $x$.

Comment: If $x = \pi$ then ...

Comment: That expression is not generally true.  Note that the arctangent, as a function, spans between $-n\pi/2$ to $-\pi/2+\pi$.  So, for any $x$ that is outside that interval, the expession is incorrect.

Comment: If you provide a precise definition of the arc tangent, the solution will come on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take for granted that $\arctan x$ is a univocal function defined for all $x$, because $\tan x$ has the codomain $\mathbb R$, and such that $\tan(\arctan x))=x$. Then applying the tangent to the identity $\arctan(\tan x)=y$, we have

$$\tan(\arctan(\tan(x)))=\tan y$$ i.e. $$\tan x=\tan y.$$

This doesn't mean that $x=y$, but $x=y+k\pi$, because of the periodicity.

Then the LHS and RHS of the orginal equation can differ in a multiple of $\pi$ (when they are defined).

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan(\tan x)$ is the *unique* representative of the coset $\;x+\mathbf Z\pi\in\mathbf R/\mathbf Z\pi\;$ which belongs to the interval $\bigl(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr)$.